# Observer doesn't save order

Tags: php, magento, observer-pattern

I've build an observer which listens on the `sales_convert_quote_to_order` event. The event is triggered and I just want to add a value to an attribute of the order. The attribute is set - as printed in the log - but magento doesn't save the order. What I'm doing wrong?

Observer.php

```
public function addLangToOrder($observer){
        Mage::log('catching convert_quote_to_order_after');
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $order->setCustomerLanguage(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode());
        $order->save();
        Mage::log($order->getCustomerLanguage());
    }
```

config.xml

```
<events>
    <sales_convert_quote_to_order>
        <observers>
            <accustomer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Ac_Customer_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>addLangToOrder</method>
            </accustomer>
        </observers>
    </sales_convert_quote_to_order>
</events>
```

I've added the attribute `customer_language` through an install script

```
$customer_lang = 'customer_language';
$installer->addAttribute('order', $customer_lang, array('type'=>'varchar'));
```

The `customer_language` column is present in my sales_flat_order table. But it doesn't get saved.

I'm using Magento 1.4.1.1

Comment: Is your event triggered?  //Ooops sorry, I didn't read it properly...

Comment: Which Version of Magento are you talking about? Can you please specify..!

Comment: Sorry Subesh forgotten the version. Check my update please

Comment: isn't there anything in your log files? and also, couldn't you use the existing `store_id` order attribute instead of creating a new one? It looks like duplicate to me.

Comment: No nothing in my logs. I don't know where do you see duplicates. I don't store the store_id - I want to store the store->code attribute to my order...

Comment: Can you use these `$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $order->setCustomerLanguage(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode());`
Omit the Save method. Because as I see in the code the event is fired in Mage_Sales_Model_Convert_Quote class within a method toOrder which returns the order object. The save part must have been done somewhere else. So just set the additional data to your order object in your observer and leave Magento to save your data to DB.. Unless if there is nothing wrong in your attribute creation.

Comment: Hi Subesh, thanks for your comment! I tried it your way but nothing happens (sadly)

Comment: Just some debug ideas: set the customer_language field directly for an order in the database, load that very same order in your code and check that you get the correct value when you read it with `$order->getCustomerLanguage()`. Also, usually we `return $this` at the end of event observer methods (although I don't believe that this is the cause since the event dispatcher code in `Mage/Core/Model/App.php` does not use method chaining).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add your attribute to both - `quote` **and** `sales` model - to make this work.

As Magento will copy a defined `<fieldset>`* from `quote` to `order`, you need to extend the `config.xml` of your overriding class accordingly, too:

```
<config>
    <!-- : -->
    <global>
        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote>
                <customer_language><to_order>*</to_order></customer_language>
            </sales_convert_quote>
        </fieldsets>
    </global>
    <!-- : -->
</config>
```

---

*<sub>see the `config.xml` of `Mages_Sales`</sub>

Answer (score 5):

is there a transaction occurring before this? its been my experience that trying to save a model when a transaction is still in progress doesn't work. I had to move the observer to another event after the transaction like "sales_model_service_quote_submit_after" instead.